# How to obtain value of field in base type

Tags: c#, .net, oop, inheritance, reflection

I have a class derived from base class which has a private field. 
How can I get the BaseType field value?

```
public class SuperClass : BaseClass
{
}

public class BaseClass
{
    private object theField;
}
```

I have the SuperClass instance and the code should be something like:

```
var baseType = super.GetType().BaseType;
var fieldInfo = baseType.GetField("theField", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

Now how can I get the value from fieldInfo? Or my approach is wrong?

Comment: Your names are *very* confusing, as `SuperClass` is a *derived* class... it's a subclass, not (Java terminology) a superclass.

Comment: If it's private, it's not supposed to be available to outsiders, ever.

Comment: @alex, There are many situations where you need to retrieve private members. see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8796346/finding-the-primary-key-from-a-classmapt-with-fluent-nhibernate) question

Comment: @gdoron I'd say that you're not supposed to *need* private members either, but maybe it's just a matter of taste and how well-coded things are.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [FieldInfo.GetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo.getvalue.aspx)

```
fieldInfo.GetValue(this)
```

Incidentally you don't need `super.GetType` - you can just do:

```
this.GetType().BaseType
```

Equally, since you know the base type - it's possibly marginally quicker to do

```
typeof(BaseClass).GetField("theField" ....)
```

### Update

I used `this` because your question implies that the code you've written is part of `SuperClass` because you have written (despite it not being valid C#):

```
var baseType = super.GetType().BaseType;
```

If that's not the case, and you have an instance of `SuperClass` then this will do:

```
var obj = new SuperClass();
var privateValue = typeof(BaseClass).GetField("theField", 
  BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(obj);
```

I would actually *strongly recommend against* using `obj.GetType().BaseType` - because your reflection will immediately break if you choose to inject a base between `SuperClass` and `BaseClass`; whereas using `typeof(BaseClass)` won't - unless you actually remove `BaseClass` from `SuperClass`'s inheritance tree.

Comment: `this`? I need the value outside the `SuperClass` class

Comment: your example implies that, because you are using `super`, that the code you've written is in the `SuperClass` type.  If that's not the case, then perhaps you've made a typo in the question.  If it is, however, `this` *inherits* `BaseClass` therefore the field is actually part of `this`, but the part whose type is `BaseClass`