# Detecting a table's primary key

Tags: c#, reflection, t4

I am trying to generate some custom entities and custom method to get data from database.

`ListByPrimaryKey` - the column name sometimes is "ID", "pid", "id", etc.

How can you detect that a column is a primary key using C#, using T4 templates?

```
protected void GenerateListByMethods( Table table)
{
    WriteLine("#region ListBy\n");

    WriteLine("\n\tpublic List<"+Prefix+table.Name+"> ListAll()\n\t{\n\t  " +
        this.RepositoryNotification +
        "\n\t\t\t return Ctx.GetAll().ToList().ToCustomList<"+table.Name+","+Prefix+table.Name+">();\n\t}\n");
    foreach (Column  column in table.Columns)
    {
        switch(column.DataType.Name)
        {  // do something
```

How can you write an extension method for `column.DataType.IsPrimaryKey`?

Comment: which `ORM` are you using? Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8801227/601179) answer for `NHibernate`

Comment: Have you thought about just running a Database Query..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using SQL SERVER try to run either of the querys

```sql
SELECT  i.name AS IndexName,
        OBJECT_NAME(ic.OBJECT_ID) AS TableName,
        COL_NAME(ic.OBJECT_ID,ic.column_id) AS ColumnName
FROM    sys.indexes AS i INNER JOIN 
        sys.index_columns AS ic ON  i.OBJECT_ID = ic.OBJECT_ID
                                AND i.index_id = ic.index_id
WHERE   i.is_primary_key = 1
```

or

```sql
select * 
from sysobjects 
where xtype='pk' and 
   parent_obj in (select id from sysobjects where name='tablename')
```